# Save multiple session variables with a form

Tags: php, forms, session, session-variables

I am working on a form with fields for dimensions where a customer can fill these fields in and submit them and they will be saved in session variables. So far I succeeded 1 form, but after saving 1 time the data of the fields it needs to be possible for the costumer that he can fill in a form again (for dimensions) and still another and another etc etc.

(I started the session in top of my header)

The form:

```
<form method="POST">

   <label>A:</label>
   <input name="wz_saving_a" type="text" />

   <label>B:</label>
   <input name="wz_saving_b" type="text" />

   <input name="wz_submit_saving_1" type="submit" class="add_button" value="Add"  />

</form>
```

PHP for saving data in $_SESSION:

```
if(isset($_POST['wz_submit_saving_1'])) :

    // Save submit
    $_SESSION['wz_submit_saving_1'] = $_POST['wz_submit_saving_1'];

    // Save wz_saving_a in session
    $_SESSION['wz_saving_a'] =  $_POST['wz_saving_a'];

    // Save wz_saving_b in session
    $_SESSION['wz_saving_b'] = $_POST['wz_saving_b'];

endif;
```

After submit I show the submitted data to the costumer like:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['wz_submit_saving_1'])) : ?>

<div id="wz_config_1" class="wz_config">

<ul>
   <li>Your dimensions:</li>
   <li>A: <?php if(isset($_SESSION['wz_saving_a'])) : echo $_SESSION['wz_saving_a']; endif; ?> mm</li>
   <li>B: <?php if(isset($_SESSION['wz_saving_b'])) : echo $_SESSION['wz_saving_b']; endif; ?> mm</li>
</ul>   

<?php endif; ?>
```

So this works for 1 submit and if I submit the form the session variables of the first will be refreshed by the new data, but now I need something to do so the costumer can add multiple dimensions sets and save in the Session.

My idea was to change every name of a field by _1 _2 _3 after each form submit. But I don't know how to fix this so I hope someone can give me some advice.

I can give the url of my example if you want?

Thanks!

Comment: What I find funny is that you're using arrays troughout your example code but it never occurred to you that arrays can be multidimensional? Why do you have an array key appended with _a, _b, _c if you can simply have `$_SESSION['your_form_id']['your_form_data_key']` and be done with it?

Comment: I am just started with working with session variables so this is new for me. But do you mean you can save the session variables by specific form?

Comment: Yes, you can save data for a specific form in the $_SESSION. It's an array, you can use it any way you like.

Comment: Ok, that helps me a little bit but it don't solve my problem because I need change the form name after each submit then right? otherwise there's no second form to submit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multidimensional session arrays:

```
$_SESSION['wz_saving_b'][$_POST['wz_saving_b']] = $_POST['wz_saving_b'];
```

Or, just use [] to add new keys, but you are going to have duplicated values

```
$_SESSION['wz_saving_b'][] = $_POST['wz_saving_b'];
```

Let's say the user types in wz_saving_b the following things:

`1`, `2`, `3`

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<form method="POST" action="">

   <label>A:</label>
   <input name="wz_saving_a" type="text" />

   <label>B:</label>
   <input name="wz_saving_b" type="text" />

   <input name="wz_submit_saving_1" type="submit" class="add_button" value="Add"  />

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['wz_submit_saving_1'])):
    $_SESSION['wz_saving_b'][$_POST['wz_saving_b']] = $_POST['wz_saving_b'];
?>
<div id="wz_config_1" class="wz_config">

<ul>
   <li>Your dimensions:</li>
   <li>B: <?php if(isset($_SESSION['wz_saving_b'])): foreach($_SESSION['wz_saving_b'] as $k => $v) { echo "$v "; } endif; ?> mm</li>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>


<?php
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

Output:

```
    Your dimensions:
    B: 1 2 3 mm

array (size=1)
  'wz_saving_b' => 
    array (size=3)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '2' (length=1)
      3 => string '3' (length=1)
```

---

**The requested abstraction:**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<form method="POST" action="">

   <label>A:</label>
   <input name="wz_saving_a" type="text" />

   <label>B:</label>
   <input name="wz_saving_b" type="text" />

   <label>C:</label>
   <input name="wz_saving_c" type="text" />

   <label>D:</label>
   <input name="wz_saving_d" type="text" />

   <input name="wz_submit_saving_1" type="submit" class="add_button" value="Add"  />

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['wz_submit_saving_1'])) {
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if($key != 'wz_submit_saving_1') {
            $_SESSION[$key][] = $value;
        }
    }
}
?>
<div id="wz_config_1" class="wz_config">

<ul>
   <li>Your dimensions:</li>
   <?php foreach($_SESSION as $k => $v): ?>
    <?php foreach($v as $saving => $wz): ?>
   <li><?= strtoupper(substr($k, 10));?> : <?=$wz;?> mm</li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>


<?php
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

I did some random inputs here with some numbers. The output is:

```
    Your dimensions:
    A : 1 mm
    A : 6 mm
    A : 5 mm
    B : 1 mm
    B : 6 mm
    B : 5 mm
    C : 4 mm
    C : 8 mm
    C : 5 mm
    D : 4 mm
    D : 7 mm
    D : 5 mm

array (size=4)
  'wz_saving_a' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '6' (length=1)
      2 => string '5' (length=1)
  'wz_saving_b' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '6' (length=1)
      2 => string '5' (length=1)
  'wz_saving_c' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '4' (length=1)
      1 => string '8' (length=1)
      2 => string '5' (length=1)
  'wz_saving_d' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '4' (length=1)
      1 => string '7' (length=1)
      2 => string '5' (length=1)
```

---

Based on the provided code, this should work, I tried to input one time `1` and `2` mm on position `x`, and then `4` and `5` mm on position `y`, the output was:

```
Rechte sparing 1

        Formaat van de sparing:
        A: 1 mm
        B: 2 mm
        Positionering van de sparing:
        x

Rechte sparing 1

        Formaat van de sparing:
        A: 4 mm
        B: 5 mm
        Positionering van de sparing:
        y
```

Code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['wz_submit_saving_1'])) :

    $straight_saving = array(
        'wz_str_saving' => $_POST['wz_str_saving'],
        'wz_saving_a' => $_POST['wz_saving_a'],
        'wz_saving_b' => $_POST['wz_saving_b'],
        'wz_submit_saving_1' => $_POST['wz_submit_saving_1']
    );

    $_SESSION['straight_saving'][] = $straight_saving;

endif;


if(isset($_SESSION['straight_saving'])) : 

    foreach($_SESSION['straight_saving'] as $sav) {

?>

<div class="wz_config">

    <h3>Rechte sparing 1</h3>


    <ul>
        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Formaat van de sparing:</li>
                <li>A: <?php echo $sav['wz_saving_a']; ?> mm</li>
                <li>B: <?php echo $sav['wz_saving_b']; ?> mm</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <ul>
                <li>Positionering van de sparing:</li>
                <li><?php echo $sav['wz_str_saving']; ?></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="clear"></div>

</div><!--End wz_config_1-->

<?php } endif; ?>
```

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand how this can fix my problem. This is the url of my work, maybe you can understand my question better then. You can see that you can store 1 form but I need to store more forms. http://www.glasbestellen.nl/keukenwand-rechte-sparingen

Comment: What you did not understand. It solves your problem, because in $_SESSION['wz_saving_b'] you have array with the keys of the POST-ed value. It can be done better, but right now this is my example. See my edit for printing.

Comment: Okay thanks for your help, I understand not completely but I am going to try.

Comment: I changed a little bit the code. You don't need more forms. Everytime the user turns back to add dimensions they will be stored and printed.

Comment: Okay thanks. But I need to display the whole "wz_config" with A and B in it for each submitted form where you are now applying it only on B.  Can I do that by using your foreach statement but then for each $_SESSION['wz_submit_saving_1'] right?

Comment: Well, do it for A, too?

Comment: Yes, but how can I do it for the whole "wz_config". I need to "copy" the whole "wz_config" div with all information in it each time someone fills in the form. Can I do that with <?php if(isset($_SESSION['wz_submit_saving_1'])): foreach($_SESSION['wz_submit_saving_1'] as $k => $v) { ?> HERE THE CONFIG  <?php } endif; ?>

Comment: Not exactly. You can make iteration through suffix. If you want such abstraction, see my edit. I left the old code, but made a new one also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41706/discussion-between-robbert-and-royal-bg)

Comment: Can you give the example for repeating the wz_config div with A and B in it for each submit. I tried but I can't get it work.

Comment: Did you try to move the first foreach before the <div> ?

Comment: Yes I've tried. But I think you still don't exactly understand what I mean. Can you please watch my example. You can see If you clicked the select box and fill in the dimensions A and B and click on the blue button. The div (wz_config) with data in it shows up. This div needs to show up each time you submit the form with the submitted data (saved in SESSION). http://www.glasbestellen.nl/keukenwand-rechte-sparingen

Comment: I think I should store all the data of the submit in 1 array. So the dimensions (A and B) and the submit. Is that what you say I need to use multidimensional session arrays?

Comment: You can remove the abstraction, and say explicitly to print the first foreached value from A with this from B, because right now without any hardcoded value, you will end up with iterating thourgh first key of A, then second iteration will get second key of B, which will not work for you

Comment: I worked on it and think I'm almost there, how can I show you my new code?

Comment: If you can edit the question, put it at the bottom :)

Comment: I putted my last update at the bottom. It submit the data and saved it in the session. But doesn't save more arrays so don't show more wz_config divs among each other.

Comment: My thoughts was to edit your question, not my answer, but however, I saw them. I put the minor edits. It should work as expected now. See my edited answer at the bottom

Comment: Oh sorry.. But thanks! Problem solved. I appreciate your help very much. Have a nice day