# How can I get the information from two forms on my php server at once?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on a html form. I have used the below code to setup the form.

```
<div class="formElementsWrapper formElementsUsername">
            <label for="userid" class="hidden">Username</label>
            <input type="text" accesskey="U" id="userid" class="formElement formElementText" name="j_username" maxlength="14" value="" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="formElementsWrapper formElementsPassword">
            <label for="password" class="hidden">Password</label>
            <input type="password" accesskey="P" id="password" class="formElement formElementPassword" name="j_password" maxlength="32" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div id="saveuid" class="formElementsWrapper formElementsSaveUsername">
            <input type="checkbox" accesskey="S" id="saveusername" class="c29link formElement formElementCheckbox" name="saveusername" data-content-id="c29content-save-username" triggerhover="false" isclickable="true">
            <label for="saveusername" class="lsc">Save username<span class="hidden">Opens a dialog</span></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="save-username" id="save-username" value="false">
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnuserid" id="hdnuserid">
        </div>
        <div class="formSubmit">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign On" name="btnSignon" id="btnSignon" class="c7" data-mrkt-tracking-id="3d6c76ba-9d34-4def-977d-a79cb8afc738">
```

When I submit this form, I want this form to take me to the next form page which has other information. I have done this using the php code

```
<form action="verification.php" method="post"> 

<div class="formElementsWrapper formElementsUsername">
            <label for="userid" class="hidden">Username</label>
            <input type="text" accesskey="U" id="userid" class="formElement formElementText" name="j_username" maxlength="14" value="" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="formElementsWrapper formElementsPassword">
            <label for="password" class="hidden">Password</label>
            <input type="password" accesskey="P" id="password" class="formElement formElementPassword" name="j_password" maxlength="32" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div id="saveuid" class="formElementsWrapper formElementsSaveUsername">
            <input type="checkbox" accesskey="S" id="saveusername" class="c29link formElement formElementCheckbox" name="saveusername" data-content-id="c29content-save-username" triggerhover="false" isclickable="true">
            <label for="saveusername" class="lsc">Save username<span class="hidden">Opens a dialog</span></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="save-username" id="save-username" value="false">
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnuserid" id="hdnuserid">
        </div>
        <div class="formSubmit">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign On" name="btnSignon" id="btnSignon" class="c7" data-mrkt-tracking-id="3d6c76ba-9d34-4def-977d-a79cb8afc738">
```

Finally when I submit the second form, i want both the information on the first form and the second form to be sent to my php server through my index.php file on the server.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are both forms identical? or I'm missing something ?

Comment: Use php session.

Comment: @Accountantم Yes The forms are identical. . and i want both information on both forms to be sent. How can i get this done. The code above is just an example for this purpose.

Comment: @RohitRasela How can i do this. Can you explain.. Thanks.

Comment: You are working with php right? When you submit the form store the first form data in session an redirect to second form if you want the first form data in second form you can fetch the data from session variable. And when will you submit the second form get the first form data from the session and second form data by post. By this method you can create a functionality that if you want to go back to the second form you can fill the first form data from the session variable this. so this method will not loss your first form data.

Comment: @RohitRasela Thank you for the information. Yes i am working with PHP. Can you give me a code that enables me to fetch first form data. Also do i insert this code on the second form for it to retrieve first form data.  Also please note that the second form is included in another php file different from the file where the first form is included. Please advice if i am getting this right.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144651/save-multiple-session-variables-with-a-form

Comment: @RohitRasela The essence of this is for me to be able to setup a verification page for anyone that submits the form on the first page. Such that after submission of first form, you get redirected to another verification form.  Thus after submission of the verification form, i get the information from both the first form and the verification form.

Comment: You can simply work with session variable and implement your own logic.

Comment: @RohitRasela Thanks again. However i would need you to put me through this because i am not a programmer. I am only using basic knowledge to try to get this done. Pls help

Comment: @anwarul-islam i am awaiting your response

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you can do this on one page by using a POST value from each form along with a series of if/elseif statements as demonstrated below;

```
<?php

//check if the "page" value is NOT set and if true show the "page 1 form"

if(!ISSET($_POST["page"])){

//open the form tag
echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post">';
echo '<div class="formElementsWrapper formElementsUsername">
            <label for="userid" class="hidden">Username</label>
            <input type="text" accesskey="U" id="userid" class="formElement formElementText" name="j_username" maxlength="14" value="" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="formElementsWrapper formElementsPassword">
            <label for="password" class="hidden">Password</label>
            <input type="password" accesskey="P" id="password" class="formElement formElementPassword" name="j_password" maxlength="32" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div id="saveuid" class="formElementsWrapper formElementsSaveUsername">
            <input type="checkbox" accesskey="S" id="saveusername" class="c29link formElement formElementCheckbox" name="saveusername" data-content-id="c29content-save-username" triggerhover="false" isclickable="true">
            <label for="saveusername" class="lsc">Save username<span class="hidden">Opens a dialog</span></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="save-username" id="save-username" value="false">
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnuserid" id="hdnuserid">
        </div>';

//now we set the "page value" by using a hidden input field
echo '        <div class="formSubmit">
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="1" />
            <input type="submit" value="Sign On" name="btnSignon" id="btnSignon" class="c7" data-mrkt-tracking-id="3d6c76ba-9d34-4def-977d-a79cb8afc738">';

//always remember to close all your tags

echo '</div></form>';

}
//now we end that "if statement" with the bracket above and below create another check, for page 2
elseif($_POST["page"]==1){

//if this parameter shows as page one continue below

//start the session
session_start();
//collect the data from the first form and put it into a session values
$_SESSION["uid"] = $_POST["userid"];

//display the second form
echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post"> 

<div class="formElementsWrapper formElementsUsername">
            <label for="userid" class="hidden">Username</label>
            <input type="text" accesskey="U" id="userid" class="formElement formElementText" name="j_username" maxlength="14" value="" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div class="formElementsWrapper formElementsPassword">
            <label for="password" class="hidden">Password</label>
            <input type="password" accesskey="P" id="password" class="formElement formElementPassword" name="j_password" maxlength="32" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
        <div id="saveuid" class="formElementsWrapper formElementsSaveUsername">
            <input type="checkbox" accesskey="S" id="saveusername" class="c29link formElement formElementCheckbox" name="saveusername" data-content-id="c29content-save-username" triggerhover="false" isclickable="true">
            <label for="saveusername" class="lsc">Save username<span class="hidden">Opens a dialog</span></label>
            <input type="hidden" name="save-username" id="save-username" value="false">
            <input type="hidden" name="hdnuserid" id="hdnuserid">
        </div>';

//again create the page number
echo '        <div class="formSubmit">
            <input type="hidden" name="page" value="2" />
<input type="submit" value="Sign On" name="btnSignon" id="btnSignon" class="c7" data-mrkt-tracking-id="3d6c76ba-9d34-4def-977d-a79cb8afc738">';

//again, remember to close your tags
echo '<div></form>';

//end if statement
}

//check if page 2 is complete
elseif($_POST["page"]==2){

echo $_SESSION["uid"] . ', your form has been completed';
echo '<br><br>';
echo 'Thanks for your submission';

}

?>
```

In the final elseif statement you will need to do something with the values but this should get you started on your project.

Before you go releasing anything onto the internet however I would **strongly** advise you read up on some of the essentials, make sure to include;
 - Protecting against SQL Injection
 - Encrypting passwords safely and securely
 - Working with arrays

**You DON'T want to be passing passwords around in the session headers either so be careful how you plan forward**

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Please use php session to store your first form data temporary before fetching data from second form data.

after submit first form you can store by php function:

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['first_form'] = $_POST;
```

by doing this you can redirect to second form. And fetch data from that. Then submit them

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Can you explain in which of the forms do i insert this php function. Do i include it in the first or second form??? Also second form is included in a different php files.. Is this okay or can be a problem. Please explain as i do not have extensive programming knowledge. Thanks

Comment: It's totally okay. You need just another php file for action file for every form. And that php file need to be same for two forms. 

submit first form and store data in session. and send user to fill second form after submit second form you can access data from every forms

Comment: after submitting second form you can access first form data from print_r($_SESSION['first_form']) and second form data from $_POST

Comment: Thank you. Can you please give me a pratical example using the code i put in the question.  I would appreciate that. The first form code is included in an index.html file and the second form is included in a verification.php file... Can you use the codes as an example for my better understanding. I appreciate this. Also Note: The codes for the two forms are the same.

Comment: I am awaiting your response sir

Comment: I have tried the code you gave and im not getting the result of both forms. I am not sure if i am inputing the code in the right part of the scripts. And also advice on where to insert code to get both form data